Is there a name for a hybrid of Camel Case and Kebab Case?
I recently released a new CSS framework that uses a lot of CSS variables and am working on some publication material to put it more in the spotlight.  The way I define the variables looks like
var(--loMed-1-5)

As you see I'm using camel case in one part but am overall using kebab case.  I haven't seen this anywhere else so I've just been calling it camel kebab in my own little world.  I just want to see if there's already an established name for this before I release a publication calling it something else.  Does anybody know of something different or would it be safe to just stick with camel kebab?

never heard of any official hybrid casing before. Please ensure the term camel kebab doesn't confuse your publication readers. I'm guessing your variable names var(--loMed-1-5) are following a pattern. Maybe explaining the pattern would be helpful for your readers? like var(--<nameInCamelCase>-<majorVariantNum>-<minorVariantNum>)

It might be clearer to readers if you simply called it semantic naming and included a clear definition at the start of your documentation about the convention your type of semantic naming adheres to.
